# Creating Order and Collecting Totals

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, tax, quote, create-order

I'm having a very hard time collecting the right totals when creating an order by code *(magento 1.9, php5.4)*. I'm creating a quote as you noramlly would, added products and shipping/billing address, and now I'm collection the subtotal/shipping/taxes/grandtotal, and im not getting the right calculations.

For the example below, I have the following:

```
Product Price is 100
Taxes on Product Price is 25
Shipping Amount is 10
Shipping Taxes is 2.5
Grand total should be 137.5
```

When when executing `$quote->collectTotals();` to get the order grand total, im always getting `110` for `$quote->getGrandTotal()` or `$quote->getShippingAddress()->getGrandTotal()`. I should be getting `137.5`.

So I google around and did my homework, and apparently there was a problem in the order of the collection, so magento was collecting using the following order:

```
tax_shipping
nominal
subtotal
freeshipping
tax_subtotal
weee 
shipping 
discount 
grand_total
msrp 
tax
```

and the following total amounts were calculated:

[image]

So it looked like `grand_total` was calculated before adding the tax, and this is why I was getting `110` instead of `137.5`, which makes sense, since all what the grand total class does is to sum up the total:

```
class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand
     */
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $grandTotal     = $address->getGrandTotal();
        $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();

        $store      = $address->getQuote()->getStore();
        $totals     = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());
        $totals     = $store->roundPrice($totals);
        $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());
        $baseTotals = $store->roundPrice($baseTotals);

        $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal+$totals);
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal+$baseTotals);
        return $this;
    }
```

So I though if I changed the order of the collection, by moving the grand_total collection after the tax collection, this would solve my problem, so used i overrode the order using this simple extension https://github.com/hartmut-co-uk/magento-php7-totals-fix, after all it looked like a lot of people are facing the same issue with PHP7 and PHP5.5, although im using PHP5.4, i thought i would give it a shot, considering how desperate i am.

Now things are a bit different, the collection total changed to:

```
nominal
freeshipping
tax_subtotal
msrp
subtotal
weee
shipping
tax_shipping
discount
tax
grand_total
```

So I though all my problem went away, but for some reason, now the tax are not calculated the right way, I'm getting `2.5` for the tax instead of `27.5`

[image]

I know the post is super long and can be hard to follow, but hopefully I was able to explain the problem. So the first question is:

1. Why grand_total collector is not called in the right order in the first place.
2. I have no idea what to do next. Suggestions are strongly welcomed :D.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your tax calculation settings at **"Admin - System - Configuration - Tax"**:

- Tax Calculation Method Based On: **`Total`**
- Catalog Prices: *depends on your stored product prices*
- Shipping Prices: *depends on your stored product prices*
- Apply Customer Tax: **`After Discount`**
- Apply Tax On: **`Custom price if available`**

---

Edit:

[image]

Comment: settings looks fine, please find the tax config screenshot http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2615654/208233803086acea5d6ec4ae4f18e304

Comment: Also checked all other tax setting?